# How to parse a tree in python?

Tags: python, parsing

I have an expression as follow: ( root (AA ( CC) (DD) ) (BB (CC) (DD) ) )

I want to parse this expression using recursion and I created a tree class but I'm stuck after this man.

This looks this the following tree.

```
                   root
                     |
                ____________
              AA           BB
              |             |  
       __________         ___________
      CC      DD          CC      DD
```

The output should look like this:

```
Root -> AA BB
AA -> CC DD
BB -> CC DD
```

My tree class look like the following:

```
 class tree_parsing(object):

     def __init__(self, element=None):
         self.element = element
         self.children = []
```

Basically I want to store the children in a list member variable of the class. Can someone help figure this problem out? Thank You.

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly where you're starting from.  Is the task to parse the text string "( root (AA ( CC) (DD) ) (BB (CC) (DD) ) )"?

Comment: Yes the input would be a string and spaces can be ignored.

Comment: Sounds like you want to implement breath first search, wikipedia gives some hints including a rough implementation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: OK.  I'd suggest proceeding as follows:  Scan the string left to right.  Parse the left parenthesis to mean "start a new tree node class, possibly as a child of the one I'm working on now." Ignore spaces and parse non-parentheses as portions of a name that will be completed by a parenthesis (either open or closed).  Closed parenthesis will have a meaning that will become clear as you go, I think.  Hopefully, that will give you a start.

Comment: BFS should be the last step: _the output_. But for building the tree, he'll certainly need to write some lexer and parser - which ain't that straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
#!python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Node(object):
  def __init__(self, name, left=None, right=None):
    self.name = name
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

def dump_tree(node):
  if node.left or node.right:
    left = 'None' if node.left is None else node.left.name
    right = 'None' if node.right is None else node.right.name
    print('{0} -> {1} {2}'.format(node.name, left, right))

  if node.left:
    dump_tree(node.left)

  if node.right:
    dump_tree(node.right)


Root = Node(
  'Root', Node('AA', Node('CC'), Node('DD')),
          Node('BB', Node('CC'), Node('DD')),
)

dump_tree(Root)
```

prints:

```
$ python example.py
Root -> AA BB
AA -> CC DD
BB -> CC DD
$
```